# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Rest API $expand query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, expand

I am trying to query the ServerRelativeUrl to get the list item attachment. Below is the xml.  d/results(0)/ServerRelativeUrl always returns empty. I can query the Id properly with d/results(0)/Id just can't get the filename or url.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="http://bsktoday/depts/accounting/_api/" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" 
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<id>c00374cf-6d42-462b-89ed-f3fba5204961</id>
<title />
<updated>2018-07-06T19:19:40Z</updated>
<entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;">
    <id>af5554dd-4332-4374-adaf-0cc41fd67c62</id>
    <category term="SP.Data.Work_x0020_In_x0020_ProcessListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'c194f5c3-1759-4df5-baa1-ae45237d2589')/Items(53)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AttachmentFiles" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AttachmentFiles" href="Web/Lists(guid'c194f5c3-1759-4df5-baa1-ae45237d2589')/Items(53)/AttachmentFiles">
        <m:inline>
            <feed>
                <id>1509e208-782e-41a4-bb13-ad724cdb90dd</id>
                <title />
                <updated>2018-07-06T19:19:40Z</updated>
                <entry>
                    <id>http://bsktoday/depts/accounting/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c194f5c3-1759-4df5-baa1-ae45237d2589')/Items(53)/AttachmentFiles('testing1.csv')</id>
                    <category term="SP.Attachment" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'c194f5c3-1759-4df5-baa1-ae45237d2589')/Items(53)/AttachmentFiles('testing1.csv')" />
                    <title />
                    <updated>2018-07-06T19:19:40Z</updated>
                    <author>
                        <name />
                    </author>
                    <content type="application/xml">
                        <m:properties>
                            <d:ServerRelativeUrl>/depts/accounting/Lists/Work In Process/Attachments/53/testing1.csv</d:ServerRelativeUrl>
                        </m:properties>
                    </content>
                </entry>
            </feed>
        </m:inline>
    </link>
    <title />
    <updated>2018-07-06T19:19:40Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">53</d:Id>
            <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">53</d:ID>
            <d:Attachments m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:Attachments>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the XML returned, then you will probably need something like this:

```
d/results(0)/feed/entry/link(1)/inline/feed/entry/content/properties/ServerRelativeUrl
```

If you are returning JSON, the format is a bit simpler:

```
yourJavaScriptObject.d.ServerRelativeUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion but the answer I figured out was a slightly different query to the API.

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list name here')/items(item id here)/AttachmentFiles

then return 
d/results(0)/serverrelativeurl